# Spring and hibernate error "Declaring class is not found in the inheritance state hierarchy"

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I am new to spring and hibernate and trying to use @ElementCollection and @Embeddable,
Iv'e seen some close examples but not quite what i need, I have a "top" class that has an @IdClass and in that i want to have an @ElementCollection.
Environment(and it's id) classes:

```
class EnvironmentId implements Serializable {
String userName;
String envName;
}

@Entity
@IdClass(EnvironmentId.class)
public class Environment {
@Id
String userName;

@Id
String envName;

@Column
String location;

     @ElementCollection
List<IncludedPRPoint> includedPRPoint;

     ... getters setters and constructures ...
}
```

IncludedPRPoint class:

```
@Embeddable
public class IncludedPRPoint implements Serializable {

String prPointName;
String description;
String mainSite;

     ... Getters setters and constructors ...
}
```

when trying to use i get exception "Declaring class is not found in the inheritance state hierarchy: ..."

Am I doing something wrong?

```
Edit full stacktrace:

[11:34:01:433 GMT+02:00 11/02/14] 0000006e webapp        E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp logServletError SRVE0293E: [Servlet Error]-[mvc-dispatcher]: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor#0': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'h8EntityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [build-spring-jpa.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.annotations.common.AssertionFailure: Declaring class is not found in the inheritance state hierarchy: demo.includedPRPoint
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:532)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:198)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:741)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:383)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:283)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.notifyServletContextCreated(WebApp.java:1651)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl.initialize(WebAppImpl.java:410)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroupImpl.addWebApplication(WebGroupImpl.java:88)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.VirtualHostImpl.addWebApplication(VirtualHostImpl.java:169)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApp(WSWebContainer.java:748)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApplication(WSWebContainer.java:633)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.install(WebContainerImpl.java:422)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.start(WebContainerImpl.java:714)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1138)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.fireDeployedObjectStart(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:1369)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedModuleImpl.start(DeployedModuleImpl.java:638)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startModule(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1634)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.access$400(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:209)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl$3.run(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1569)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAs(ContextManagerImpl.java:5405)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAsSystem(ContextManagerImpl.java:5531)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.core.SecurityContext.runAsSystem(SecurityContext.java:255)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl._startModule(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1598)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:49)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor24.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:256)
    at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invokeMethod(RequiredModelMBean.java:1085)
    at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invoke(RequiredModelMBean.java:966)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:848)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:773)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl$1.run(AdminServiceImpl.java:1335)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.util.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:118)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl.invoke(AdminServiceImpl.java:1228)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.application.sync.StartDeploymentTask.startDeployment(StartDeploymentTask.java:236)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.application.sync.StartDeploymentTask.fineGrainUpdate(StartDeploymentTask.java:187)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.application.sync.StartDeploymentTask.performTask(StartDeploymentTask.java:99)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.application.sync.AppBinaryProcessor$ExpandApp.expand(AppBinaryProcessor.java:1705)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.application.sync.AppBinaryProcessor.postProcessSynchronousExt(AppBinaryProcessor.java:745)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.bla.sync.BLABinaryProcessor.postProcess(BLABinaryProcessor.java:575)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.bla.sync.BLABinaryProcessor.onChangeCompletion(BLABinaryProcessor.java:452)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.repository.FileRepository.postNotify(FileRepository.java:1936)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.repository.FileRepository.update(FileRepository.java:1445)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.repository.client.LocalConfigRepositoryClient.update(LocalConfigRepositoryClient.java:189)
    at com.ibm.ws.sm.workspace.impl.WorkSpaceMasterRepositoryAdapter.update(WorkSpaceMasterRepositoryAdapter.java:657)
    at com.ibm.ws.sm.workspace.impl.RepositoryContextImpl.update(RepositoryContextImpl.java:1998)
    at com.ibm.ws.sm.workspace.impl.RepositoryContextImpl.synch(RepositoryContextImpl.java:1946)
    at com.ibm.ws.sm.workspace.impl.WorkSpaceImpl.synch(WorkSpaceImpl.java:549)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.configservice.ConfigServiceImpl.save(ConfigServiceImpl.java:717)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:49)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor24.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:256)
    at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invokeMethod(RequiredModelMBean.java:1085)
    at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invoke(RequiredModelMBean.java:966)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:848)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:773)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl$1.run(AdminServiceImpl.java:1335)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.util.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:118)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl.invoke(AdminServiceImpl.java:1228)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.AdminServiceDelegator.invoke(AdminServiceDelegator.java:181)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.ipc.CallRouter.route(CallRouter.java:247)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.ipc.IPCConnectorInboundLink.doWork(IPCConnectorInboundLink.java:353)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.ipc.IPCConnectorInboundLink$IPCConnectorReadCallback.complete(IPCConnectorInboundLink.java:595)
    at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLReadServiceContext$SSLReadCompletedCallback.complete(SSLReadServiceContext.java:1784)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1650)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'h8EntityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [build-spring-jpa.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.annotations.common.AssertionFailure: Declaring class is not found in the inheritance state hierarchy: demo.includedPRPoint
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1486)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:198)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:420)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactoryUtils.beansOfTypeIncludingAncestors(BeanFactoryUtils.java:277)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.detectPersistenceExceptionTranslators(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:79)
    at org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationAdvisor.(PersistenceExceptionTranslationAdvisor.java:70)
    at org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor.setBeanFactory(PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor.java:85)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeAwareMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1506)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1474)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524)
    ... 88 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.annotations.common.AssertionFailure: Declaring class is not found in the inheritance state hierarchy: demo.includedPRPoint
    at org.hibernate.cfg.BinderHelper.getMappedSuperclassOrNull(BinderHelper.java:656)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.PropertyBinder.bind(PropertyBinder.java:234)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.PropertyBinder.makePropertyValueAndBind(PropertyBinder.java:203)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.processElementAnnotations(AnnotationBinder.java:2013)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.fillComponent(AnnotationBinder.java:2385)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.fillComponent(AnnotationBinder.java:2288)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder.bindManyToManySecondPass(CollectionBinder.java:1399)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder.bindStarToManySecondPass(CollectionBinder.java:735)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder$1.secondPass(CollectionBinder.java:670)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.CollectionSecondPass.doSecondPass(CollectionSecondPass.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.originalSecondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1591)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1366)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1731)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:905)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:890)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:74)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:286)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:310)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1545)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1483)
    ... 103 more
```

Comment: The bit right after the colon where it specifies the source of the problem is rather important. Always post stack traces, not just partial error messages.

Comment: I believe this can happen when you mix private / public fields, getters, setters, or use a annotation like `@Id` inside the embeddable. a bit weird

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to put `@Embedded` on your `List<?> includedPRPoint`. You have to mentioned the embedded object so that hibernate can know about its class.

Refer [this](http://www.dzone.com/tutorials/java/hibernate/hibernate-example/hibernate-mapping-component-using-annotations-1.html) example for more details where to put which annotation.

Comment: `@ElementCollection @Embedded 
List<IncludedPRPoint> includedPRPoint;` didnt help :\